# Qpushbutton not being displayed

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code to display a pushbutton, i am new to qt and can't figure out why its not working.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QtWidgets>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   QWidget* wdg = new QWidget(this);
   QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(wdg);
   button->setText(tr("something"));
   setCentralWidget(wdg);//line 1
   ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

if i remove line1 then the button is being displayed but it is not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ui->setupUi(this);` is called, the user interface that is created in Qt designer stored in `.ui` file is initialized. It constructs the widgets and calls `setCentralWidget` internally. So when it is called the central widget is replaced by the one you set.

Either make the user interface by your own and ignore `ui->setupUi(this);` or first call `ui->setupUi(this);` in the constructor and do the rest of initializations by your own if you wish.